# Python module for viewing/ JSON Schema files

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I'm looking for a Python module for loading a JSON Schema file and handling it as an object. I can do this via the regular `json` module and e.g. `dictor`, but I was hoping to find a JSON Schema specific module that can e.g. natively understand `dependencies`, `definitions` and similar concepts, providing more easy handling of the data.

To be clear, I'm not looking for a JSON Schema validation tool - but rather a JSON Schema object manager. Does something like this exist?

To illustrate the type of processing I'm looking to do, see below:

```py
def schema_lister(device,schema, path):
    path_conf = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    schema_dir = f"_static/tmp/{device}_schema.json"
    path_schema = Path(path_conf,schema_dir)

    with open(path_schema) as json_file:
        schema_json = json.load(json_file)
        json_file.close()

    schema = dictor(schema_json,path)

    for elm in schema:
        elm_schema = dictor(schema,elm)
        if elm != 'anyOf' and elm != 'dependencies' and isinstance(elm_schema, dict):
            # do things, e.g. print title, description etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `sphinx-jsonschema` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of JSON Schema editors [here](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#editors). On the same page is a list of applications that can translate a schema to a class definition, or vice versa.

Comment: I’m afraid that doesn’t answer the question: “is there a Python library for handling a JSON Schema as [properly typed?] object”.